# How can I run my pdf file in url launcher by clicking on the image button?

Tags: flutter

new NetworkImage ("https://g.fmanager.net/Image/objects/1-books/evrimAldatmacasi_8b_en.jpg")

What can I do to run my url launcher code and open the pdf viewer automatically in the browser?
launchURL() {
    launch('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uX0gdQhXR1bHaeBFvpxSo5BatAt0xqR3/view?usp=sharing');
  }

```
"    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: Text('Harun Yahya World'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,

      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.playlist_add),
          tooltip: 'air',
          onPressed: () => Uri.http("", "dfg"),
        ),

          onPressed: () => print("asasdd"),
        ),
      ],
    ),

    body: GridView.count(
        primary: false,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 2 / 3,
        children: <Widget>[
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(
                context, "/deneme/main"),
            child: Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(

                color: Colors.transparent,
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  image: new NetworkImage(
                      "https://g.fmanager.net/Image/objects/1-kitaplar/evrimAldatmacasi_8b_tr.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your network image with InkWell 
in onTap, you can get index, if you need each grid open different pdf

```
return Center(
            child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          print("index ${index}");
                          _launched = _launchInBrowser("http://your pdf link here");
                        },
                        child: "your network image here",
                  );




Future<void> _launched;
String _phone = '';

Future<void> _launchInBrowser(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url, forceSafariVC: false, forceWebView: false);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Here is my full working code, you can replace ChoiceCard logical to NetworkImage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = "Grid List";

    return MaterialApp(
        title: title,
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(title),
            ),
            body: GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                children: List.generate(choices.length, (index) {
                  return Center(
                    child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          print("index ${index}");
                          _launched = _launchInBrowser("http://abc/Android/sample.pdf");
                        },
                        child: ChoiceCard(choice: choices[index])),
                  );
                }))));
  }
}

Future<void> _launched;
String _phone = '';

Future<void> _launchInBrowser(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url, forceSafariVC: false, forceWebView: false);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'Bicycle', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  const Choice(title: 'Boat', icon: Icons.directions_boat),
  const Choice(title: 'Bus', icon: Icons.directions_bus),
  const Choice(title: 'Train', icon: Icons.directions_railway),
  const Choice(title: 'Walk', icon: Icons.directions_walk),
  const Choice(title: 'Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'Bicycle', icon: Icons.drafts),
  const Choice(title: 'Boat', icon: Icons.dvr),
  const Choice(title: 'Bus', icon: Icons.copyright),
  const Choice(title: 'Train', icon: Icons.cloud_off),
  const Choice(title: 'Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'Bicycle', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  const Choice(title: 'Boat', icon: Icons.directions_boat),
  const Choice(title: 'Bus', icon: Icons.directions_bus),
  const Choice(title: 'Train', icon: Icons.directions_railway),
  const Choice(title: 'Walk', icon: Icons.directions_walk),
  const Choice(title: 'Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'Bicycle', icon: Icons.drafts),
  const Choice(title: 'Boat', icon: Icons.dvr),
  const Choice(title: 'Bus', icon: Icons.copyright),
  const Choice(title: 'Train', icon: Icons.cloud_off),
  const Choice(title: 'Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'Bicycle', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  const Choice(title: 'Boat', icon: Icons.directions_boat),
  const Choice(title: 'Bus', icon: Icons.directions_bus),
  const Choice(title: 'Train', icon: Icons.directions_railway),
  const Choice(title: 'Walk', icon: Icons.directions_walk),
  const Choice(title: 'Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'Bicycle', icon: Icons.drafts),
  const Choice(title: 'Boat', icon: Icons.dvr),
  const Choice(title: 'Bus', icon: Icons.copyright),
  const Choice(title: 'Train', icon: Icons.cloud_off),
];

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);
  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1;
    return GridTile(
        child: Container(
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.5)),
      child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(choice.icon, size: 80.0, color: textStyle.color),
                  Text(choice.title, style: textStyle),
                ]),
          )),
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]